# Writing JUnit tests for more complex methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am just learning JUnit testing procedures and have gone through all the tutorials I could find. I understand the concept of implementing basic tests, such as when a method takes a couple of inputs and uses them to compute a return value. In that case, it is simple to write a test asserting what the expected return value should be.

However, what does one do when there is a more complex method to test, such as perhaps one that uses numbers generated from a Random object, or if one needs to test a method that does not return a value?

For instance, I have the following method for which I would like to write a test:

```
// Requirement 9.5.0
public void firePhotonTorpedos(TrekGUI gui, Starship target, int score)
{
    // Requirement 9.5.1.1
    // Torpedoes can either hit or miss.
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean hit = false;
    int isItAHit= rand.nextInt(10);;
    int damage = 0;


    //80 % chance of hitting target
    if(isItAHit < 8)
    {
        hit = true;
    }

    // if it was a hit, calculate damage
    if(hit)
    {
        //damage between 30 and 50
        damage = rand.nextInt(21) + 30;

        target.setHitPoints(target.getHitPoints() - damage);
    }

    this.setPhotonTorpedos(this.getPhotonTorpedos() - 1);
    // Requirement 5.4.1
    this.setEnergy(this.getEnergy() - 50);


    //if target hit but not destroyed, say so
    if(hit && target.getHitPoints() > 0)
    {
        gui.getBottomPanel().getConsole().append("\nVessel at " + target.getQuadrantLocation() + ", " + target.getSectorLocation() + " damaged.");
        gui.getBottomPanel().getConsole().append("\n" + damage + " units damage."); 
    }
    //if target destroyed, say so and remove its ship
    // Requirement 6.2.0
    else if(hit && target.getHitPoints() < 0)
    {
        //warship is gone, so set its contains field to false and remove its icon
        target.getSectorLocation().setContainsWarship(false);
        target.getSectorLocation().getSectorView().hideWarshipIcon();

        klingonsLeft = klingonsLeft - 1;

        gui.getBottomPanel().getConsole().append("\n" + damage + " units damage.");
        gui.getBottomPanel().getConsole().append("Vessel at " + target.getQuadrantLocation() + ", " + target.getSectorLocation() + " destroyed.");

        // Increase score (bonus depending on how much energy is left)
        int bonus = this.getEnergy()/20;
        score = score + (50 + bonus);
    }
    //if it was a miss, say so
    else
    {
        gui.getBottomPanel().getConsole().append("Torpedo missed.");
    }
}
```

How would I write a formal test for this? Since I have three predicate statements in the code, I know I should have three separate paths through the code:

fire torpedo > hit (no) > end

fire torpedo > hit (yes) > calculate damage > destroyed (no) > vessel remains > end

fire torpedo > hit (yes) > calculate damage > destroyed (yes) > vessel gone > end

So if I want to get complete path coverage, for instance, I need to write at least three test cases in which these conditions are expressed. It is easy to see what those values could be. But how do I use them to write a test? Can JUnit access the boolean hit value in my code, for example, so that I can define the value without using a random number? I know I could just step through the code to see if it is working (and I have), but I have been told that I should use more formal testing means like JUnit instead.

I hope these questions make sense. I am just hoping to get a better sense of how this sort of testing is done in real world scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

> However, what does one do when there is a more complex method to test, such as perhaps one that uses numbers generated from a Random object

You find a way of controlling that `Random`. For example, you could pass it into the method, and have a parameterless overload which calls it with a `new Random()` if you really want to.

That way your tests can pass in whatever `Random` instance they want - e.g. one with a preset seed, or one which uses a mocking framework to allow you to control the values returned.

> or if one needs to test a method that does not return a value?

You test the side-effects. Your method must *have* side-effects, or it's pointless. You just need a way of *accessing* those side-effects (e.g. by calling `target.getHitPoints()`.

Now currently your method seems to have "model" side-effects *and* UI side-effects... and it's also quite long. Both of those will make it hard to test. Splitting your code up into smaller, more focused methods generally makes it easier to read *and* easier to test. Separating your UI from your business logic helps in that respect, too.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. Do you think you could show me an example of having a new Random() call the method with a parameterless overload? I do not quite understand that part.